# Spring boot application rest call gives 404 Error in tomcat for next request

Tags: spring-boot

New to spring boot. Deployed war to tomcat server. The url after deploying is - http://localhost:8080/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/. Which displays the welcome jsp page and works fine. The start button should call the controller start the project. But url call goes to http://localhost:8080/startProject instead of http://localhost:8080/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/startProject.
After manually entering /startProject after the snapshot version the project works fine. What am I missing to configure? Please help. Thank you.

My code is a below
Welcome.Jsp

```
<a type="button" class="start-btn" href="/startProject">Start New Project</a>
```

Pom.xml


4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.4.RELEASE
 

com.project
mancala
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
mancala
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

ProjectController.java

```
@Controller
```

public class ProjectController {

```
@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

@GetMapping(value = "/")
public String login() {
    return "project";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/startProject")
public String startNewGame(ModelMap model) {
    ProjectModel projectModel = projectService.startNewProject();
    model.addAttribute("projectModel", projectModel);
    return "project";
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, i thin that because when you put `/` the browser goes to the root domanin in this case `localhost:8080/` you can try `<a type="button" class="start-btn" href="startProject">Start New Project</a>` without `/` just add the path to the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, you have set the *server.servlet.context-path* property in application.properties file to *project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT*, the application is accessible via url: *http://localhost:8080/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/*.

So, all your jsp page url's must begin with the context path: */project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/***.

That means, the startProject page url in your Welcome.jsp file should look like this:

```
<a type="button" class="start-btn" href="/project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/startProject">Start New Project</a>
```

I have a sample project that could prove helpful to you here: https://github.com/nkumashi/springboot-webmvc-demo.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I know that I need to mention the context path. But the with version control how do I configure the context path without hardcoding it in the JSP. I have tried setting the context-path in application properties-server.context-path=project. But how do I configure the version dynamically with every build?

Comment: I think that's easy to handle. An example:

1. Create a variable in your controller to hold the context path.
    private String contextPath;
 
2. Inject value:
    public UserController(@Value("${server.servlet.context-path}") String contextPath)  {
  this.contextPath = contextPath;
    }

3. Load the value into your model: 
   @GetMapping("/home")
 public String register(Model model) {  
     model.addAttribute("contextPath", this.contextPath);
     return "home";
 }

4. Reference it:  
   <a href="${contextPath}/registerUser">Register User</a>